# One or more XML expansion packs are available for this file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, vsto, word-2010

**UPDATED:**

I have now added the following code based on the answers below:

```
foreach (Word.XMLSchemaReference reference in Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.XMLSchemaReferences)
{
    if (reference.NamespaceURI.Contains("ActionsPane"))
    {
        reference.Delete();
    }
}
```

This gives me no errors at design, time, but still gives the user the message described in the original question about choosing an xml expansion pack.  So the original problem hasn't been solved.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Using Visual Studio 2013, I have created a Word Document level project which has an action pane.  Everything works well.  The only problem is what when someone uses this documents action pane to insert text into the document and then save it.  The next time that saved document is opened, the user gets the following message

```
One or more XML expansion packs are available for this file.
Choose one from the list below.
No XML expansion pack
Microsoft Actions Pane 3
```

How do I stop this from happening when saved documents are opened?

Comment: i'm dealing with this problem as well. It seems to vary based on the computer being used to open the document. At this time I suspect it may have something to do with differing versions of VSTO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the XMLSchemaReferences of the word document to see if any of the Xml schema's has a namespace referring to the action pane and if so, delete it.

This needs to be done before saving.

The message you get when opening the document is because it contains a schema reference to the action pane namespace.

Something like this :

```
foreach (XMLSchemaReference reference in wordDocument.XMLSchemaReferences)
  {
    if (reference.NamespaceURI.Contains("ActionsPane"))
      {
        reference.Delete();
      }
  }
```

where `wordDocument` is the actual word document you create.

If you don't have a reference to the word document and you just want to use the current document that has the focus, you can use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument` instead of `wordDocument` in the code.

Comment: I added that code to a button click in the actionspane, so after the document has been created by the actionspane, your code is executed to make sure the reference is deleted before the user saves the document, but it gives the following design time error `The name 'wordDocument' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: The wordDocument I mention is the actual document you create. Since you have not posted your code I do not know the actual name. So substitute that with the variable containing your document.

Comment: OK, I got the code working, but it's not solving the original problem.  Please see update in question above.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem using Huron answer. Thanks Huron.
Remove your xmlreference on your active document.

for my case, i remove my xmlreference on the after mail merge event

```
void ThisApplication_MailMergeAfterMerge(Word.Document Doc, Word.Document DocResult)
    {
        DocResult.Fields.Update();
        // remove customization
        Office.DocumentProperties properties = (Office.DocumentProperties) DocResult.CustomDocumentProperties;
        properties["_AssemblyName"].Delete();
        properties["_AssemblyLocation"].Delete();
        DocResult.RemoveDocumentInformation(Word.WdRemoveDocInfoType.wdRDIDocumentProperties);


        foreach (XMLSchemaReference reference in DocResult.XMLSchemaReferences)
        {
            if (reference.NamespaceURI.Contains("ActionsPane"))
            {
                reference.Delete();
            }
        }

        ThisApplication.Visible = true;
        ThisApplication.NormalTemplate.Saved = true;
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I have my code in an actionpane instead of directly in the document itself, which I guess is causing me the problem.  How do I get this to work from an actionpane?

Comment: OK, I got the code working, but it's not solving the original problem.  Please see update in question above.